# How do I make reusable page fragments in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to create sort of **"fragments"** that I can reuse on any page. I'm aware of the `{% include %}`, but the the goal here is to put some sort of logic in them. Basically, they should act like mini-views. (?)

---

[image: Illustration]

An article recommendation block here, for example, must have some logic attached to it (querying the models maybe) and I must be able to put it in any page I want.

---

I feel like the solution there is very simple and I'm just too confused about something :)

*Perhaps this is something I can do with class mixins?*

Answer (score 0):

If you create a parent html file:

***EXAMPLE** - "base_article_generic.html"*

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8" style="border: 2px solid green;height:300px;">
        {% block article %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" style="border: 2px solid green;height:300px;">
        {% block sidebar %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8" style="border: 2px solid green;height:100px;">
        {% block article_recommmendations %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>
```

Then to re-use this use the `extends` template tag. You can then overwrite the blocks with the content specific for that template:

```html
{% extends "base_article_generic.html" %}

{% block article %}
content!
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand how to make that work if I need `article_recommendations` and `sidebar` to have their own special logic. 

There is an `article` view and I could pass context to the template for the `article_recommendations` in the `article` view, but what if I need to reuse  `article_recommendations` in many other places? How do I keep it **DRY**?

Am I wildly misunderstanding something?